# How to append output of "python --version" to a file in bash shell?

Tags: python, bash, shell, append

I'm trying to write a short script to log certain environment variables of my current shell session to file. Unfortunately the output of "python --version" seems to ignore (?) the >> operator and prints to the shell instead to the file.

My minimal (not) working example:

```
rm path.log
echo "python --version" >> path.log
python --version >> path.log
```

I would expect that the file path.log would then have the following content:

```
python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

But the line "Python 2.6.6" is printed to the shell and not to the file. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

PS: This works completely fine for

```
gcc --version
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python --version` outputs to `STDERR`.

You need to merge `STDERR` into `STDOUT`:

```
python --version >> path.log 2>&1
```

---

For reference, you can verify such behavior by saying:

```
$ python --version 1>/dev/null
Python 2.7.4
```

The `STDOUT` in the above example was redirected to `/dev/null`.  This would imply that the output is being sent to `STDERR`.

Answer (score 2):

a simpler solution is:

```
python --version 2>> path.log
```

Comment: Yup, no need to involve standard output at all